# Python pip error: "Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/"

Tags: python, proxy, pip

I'm trying to install several packages using pip. When I do this using sudo, this error occurs: "Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/". When I execute the command without sudo, the package downloads successfully, but I don't have enough permissions. What could be the reason for such different behaviour? I'm sitting behind a proxy.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Maybe try with `sudo -E`:

```
 -E          The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the secu‐
             rity policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing
             environment variables.  The security policy may return an
             error if the -E option is specified and the user does not
             have permission to preserve the environment.
```

On the assumption that your proxy settings are set in your normal user environment, but not the one you get when you run `sudo`.

Comment: Hmm, it says: "no such option: -E"

Comment: @lizarisk `-E` is an option to `sudo`, not `pip`. I made an edit to clarify

Answer (score 4):

I got this issue when trying to use `pip==1.5.4`

This is an issue related to PIP and Python's PYPI trusting SSL certificates.  If you look in the PIP log in Mac OS X at: **/Users/username/.pip/pip.log** it will give you more detail.

My workaround to get PIP back up and running after hours of trying different stuff was to go into my **site-packages** in Python whether it is in a **virtualenv** or in your normal **site-packages**, and get rid of the current PIP version.  For me I had `pip==1.5.4`

I deleted the PIP directory and the PIP egg file.  Then I ran

```
easy_install pip==1.2.1
```

This version of PIP doesn't have the SSL issue, and then I was able to go and run my normal `pip install -r requirements.txt` within my virtualenv to set up all packages that I wanted that were listed in my `requirements.txt` file.

This is also the recommended hack to get passed the issue by several people on this Google Group that I found:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/aSlPCNYcVjw

[edit]

If you have a different version of PIP installed globally, every time you create a new virtualenv it will install that version of PIP, so you will have to do this each time for each new PIP unless you change the globally installed version.  I ran into this issue when starting a new project, and had to do the fix again and revert back to `pip==1.2.1`

Answer (score 2):

From the [pip docs](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html), if you are installing behind a proxy:

python get-pip.py --proxy="[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install any packages using pip then it is better to follow below syntax:

```
sudo pip --proxy=http://username:password@proxyURL:portNumber install yolk
```

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this problem and found the answer finally solved.

You can try to add a new file`/root/.pip/pip.conf`, then write:

```
[global]
index-url=http://pypi.douban.com/simple/
```

in the file.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was different for this problem.

My system's Date and Time were not synchronized.

If the problem appears check your system data/time if that's not the problem proceed with the another suggestions.

Comment: Great Answer ! This would solve most of the problems which others failed to answer!