# "Cannot fetch index base URL" error message when attempting to install scikit-learn for Python 3

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-3.4

I try to install scikit-learn for Python 3. I do it in the following way:

```
virtualenv model_env
source  model_env/bin/activate
pip3 install sklearn
```

As a result I get the following error message:

```
Downloading/unpacking sklearn
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement sklearn
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for sklearn
```

I had the same problem with `pandas` package and I have resolved it by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

Unfortunately, the same approach does not work for the `sklearn`

```
sudo apt-get install python3-sklearn
```

**ADDED**

When I replace `sklearn` by `scikit-learn`, I have the same problem:

```
Downloading/unpacking scikit-learn
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement scikit-learn
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for scikit-learn
```

**ADDED 2**

As it has been recommended, I have try to use pip in combination with `-vvv`. Note that I use `pip3` instead of `pip`. This is what I get as the result:

```
Downloading/unpacking scikit-learn
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/scikit-learn/ (Caused by <class 'OSError'>: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/ when looking for download links for scikit-learn
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/ (Caused by <class 'OSError'>: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for scikit-learn
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for scikit-learn:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/scikit-learn/ (Caused by <class 'OSError'>: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/ when looking for download links for scikit-learn
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement scikit-learn
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
No distributions at all found for scikit-learn
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for scikit-learn

Storing debug log for failure in /home/rngorb/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: sudo pip install -U pip
sudo pip install -U scikit-learn

Comment: package name is scikit-learn

Comment: @Luca, `scikit-learn` does not work as well (see the update of my question).

Comment: Sounds like pip can't find anything on pypi ...  Try running `sudo pip -vvv install scikit-learn` for more diags.

Comment: @PeterBrittain, I tried to use `-vvv` option, the result is added to my question. Please, not that I use `pip3` instead of `pip` (I guess, it might be relevant to the problem since `pip` works for me, but not `pip3`).

Comment: The log says that pip3 cannot establish any connection at all, which either means you have no network connectivity or that your pip3/python3 install is broken.

Comment: To check the network, you could try pinging pypi.python.org.  If that doesn't work, you need to look at your network config.

Answer (score 9):

Try using

```
pip3 install scikit-learn
```

Comment: It does not help, I still have the same problem (the same error message).

Answer (score 2):

First update your pip:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Then install scikit-learn with arg "--user". Don't use sudo with pip as it will give problems:

```
pip install --user scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider the use of [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which include both packages by default and make your life easy with tools to manage [enviroments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) and [packages](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html)

Comment: @Roman I have also found using Anaconda to be the easiest way to install these packages. [Here](https://eatsleepdata.com/blogs/machine-learning/how-to-install-python-machine-learning-packages-using-anaconda) is an example of using Anaconda to install scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it with this command:

```
py -m pip install --user NAME_OF_THE_LIBRARY
```

It worked with- NumPy, SciPy, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter, pandas, sympy, nose and scikit-learn

Comment: Are you sure about that? "--user" and "NAME_OF_THE_LIBRARY" seem to not fit

Comment: Yes, I am sure. For example para o 'numpy' would be :  py -m pip install --user numpy        I have installed all libraries exactly this way. The only way that it worked in Python3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the convenience of Anaconda packages but the flexibility and minimalism of `pip` package management, I suggest you try [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html).

Once you install miniconda (remembering to `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.bashrc`), you can do this to setup your environment:

```
conda create -n myenv scikit-learn pip python=3
```

This will get you a conda env with sklearn and pip in case you want to install libraries that are not supported as a conda package. The pip runs inside the conda env.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22446215/5781248) for question [Python pip error: “Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501133/python-pip-error-cannot-fetch-index-base-url-https-pypi-python-org-simple) I would try to reinstall (and upgrade) pip with easy_install

```
easy_install pip==8.1.2
```

I tried to reproduce your problem, and installing scikit-learn succeeded after `pip install numpy` and `pip install scipy` in a virtual environment created by pyenv-3.4.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple version of Python, make sure that you are at the correct site-package path before install.

It was the case for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine. Try to install sklearn in the global environment i.e. in the terminal directly. For Ubuntu 17.04 (+ latest versions) try-

`sudo apt-get install python3-sklearn`

Similarly, for pandas

`sudo apt-get install python3-pandas`

Comment: This particularly works for deb based distributions such as Ubunut, Kali-linux, and their flavors. If there is any problem from this commands, let me know.

Comment: These are simple apt-get commands to install python libraries, there are other package managers that allows users to download older versions of libraries as well, e.g. conda, alien, etc.